check files difference with multiple folders
I would like to check when a file differ inside a backup system using snapshots.
I have several folders with the same architecture inside
ls -1 .snapshot
4-hourly.2024-04-14_0405
4-hourly.2024-04-14_0805
4-hourly.2024-04-14_1205
4-hourly.2024-04-14_1605
4-hourly.2024-04-14_2005
4-hourly.2024-04-15_0405
4-hourly.2024-04-15_0805
4-hourly.2024-04-15_1205
daily.2024-04-08_0010
daily.2024-04-09_0010
daily.2024-04-10_0010
daily.2024-04-11_0010
daily.2024-04-12_0010
daily.2024-04-13_0010
daily.2024-04-14_0010
daily.2024-04-15_0010
monthly.2024-01-01_0020
monthly.2024-02-01_0020
monthly.2024-03-01_0020
monthly.2024-04-01_0020
weekly.2024-02-25_0015
weekly.2024-03-03_0015
weekly.2024-03-10_0015
weekly.2024-03-17_0015
weekly.2024-03-24_0015
weekly.2024-03-31_0015
weekly.2024-04-07_0015
weekly.2024-04-14_0015

And I have to check a file located inside each of these folder.
For example, the goal is to see if
.snapshot/weekly.2024-04-14_0015/my/path/to/the/file.php differs from weekly.2024-04-07_0015/my/path/to/the/file.php or from .snapshot/weekly.2024-03-31_0015/my/path/to/the/file.php, or from .snapshot/weekly.2024-04-07_0015/my/path/to/the/file.php etc.
Is there an obvious simple way for this?
P-S : There are other files/folders that changed inside this folder and I cannot just compare the whole folder.

md5sum .snapshot/*//my/path/to/the/file.php

@user10489 is there a reason you have so slashes? I mean there should be no difference of using one or two slashes, right?^^

copy paste error, mostly harmless.

That sounds like an easy job for a shell loop. This should work in zsh, bash, dash…
cd .snapshot
original="weekly.2024-04-14_0015/my/path/to/the/file.php"
pathonly="$(echo "${original}" | sed 's;^[^/]*/\(.*\)$;\1;')" # cut off head directory

orig_hash=$(sha1sum "${original}" | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/')

for candidate in */"${pathonly}" ; do
  # don't compare file to itself, that'd be silly
  [[ "${candidate}" = "${original}" ]] && continue 

  cand_hash=$(sha1sum "${candidate}" | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/')

  # check hashes, so that we don't have to read the original N times
  ( [[ "${orig_hash}" = "${cand_hash}" ]] && \
  # if the hashes match, use the cmp tool to compare files byte by byte
    cmp -- "${candidate}" "${original}" ) || \
    # if either the hash equality or the content equality fail, print file name
    printf '%s differs\n' "${candidate}"
done

